# Validator peers disconnecting after producing one block

Tags: validator, private-network, peers

I am facing an issue with my private chain where I have configured 1 bootnode, 4 validator nodes and 3 non-validator nodes. When I launch the network, the peers are detected, validator node validates one block and then peers of all validator nodes get disconnected whereas peers of non-validators stay connected. Please find attached the image showing logs of one of the validators.
[image]